# Why are my navbar links only working on the homepage?

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

For some reason the contents of my navbar only lead to the correct page on the homepage of my website. On other pages if I try to navigate to a new one through the navbar, I get a 404 error. I used w3 school's template to create the bar. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```html
<!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
<div class="w3-top">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-wide w3-padding-small w3-card">
      <div id = homeID>
    <a href="index.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button r-logo">Home</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Float links to the right. Hide them on small screens -->
    <div class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop A</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
        <a href="pages/a-clothing.php">Clothing</a>
        <a href="pages/a-makeup.php">Makeup</a>
        <a href="pages/a-skin+hair.php">Skin + Hair</a>
        <a href="pages/a-accessories.php">Accessories</a>
        <a href="pages/a-household.php">Homeware</a>
      </div>
    </div>
           
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop B</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
        <a href="pages/b-clothing.php">Clothing</a>
        <a href="pages/b-makeup.php">Makeup</a>
        <a href="pages/b-skin+hair.php">Skin + Hair</a>
        <a href="pages/b-accessories.php">Accessories</a>
        <a href="pages/b-household.php">Homeware</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop C</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
        <a href="pages/c-clothing.php">Clothing</a>
        <a href="pages/c-makeup.php">Makeup</a>
        <a href="pages/c-skin+hair.php">Skin + Hair</a>
        <a href="pages/c-accessories.php">Accessories</a>
        <a href="pages/c-household.php">Homeware</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button reddo-font">Shop D</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
        <a href="pages/d-clothing.php">Clothing</a>
        <a href="pages/d-makeup.php">Makeup</a>
        <a href="pages/d-skin+hair.php">Skin + Hair</a>
        <a href="pages/d-accessories.php">Accessories</a>
        <a href="pages/d-household.php">Homeware</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Update 31/03/21) 404 means server can not find the file from the path you provided. Please move all pages/**.php files to the main folder where index.php is. Then in your current code above, delete all prefix 'pages/' for all href. Then re-use the edited navbar code for all other pages.

```html
<!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
<div class="w3-top">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-wide w3-padding-small w3-card">
      <div id = homeID>
    <a href="index.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button r-logo">Home</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Float links to the right. Hide them on small screens -->
    <div class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop A</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
        <a href="a-clothing.php">Clothing</a>
        <a href="a-makeup.php">Makeup</a>
        <a href="a-skin+hair.php">Skin + Hair</a>
        <a href="a-accessories.php">Accessories</a>
        <a href="a-household.php">Homeware</a>
      </div>
    </div>
           
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop B</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
        <a href="b-clothing.php">Clothing</a>
        <a href="b-makeup.php">Makeup</a>
        <a href="b-skin+hair.php">Skin + Hair</a>
        <a href="b-accessories.php">Accessories</a>
        <a href="b-household.php">Homeware</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button r-font">Shop C</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
        <a href="c-clothing.php">Clothing</a>
        <a href="c-makeup.php">Makeup</a>
        <a href="c-skin+hair.php">Skin + Hair</a>
        <a href="c-accessories.php">Accessories</a>
        <a href="c-household.php">Homeware</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn w3-bar-item w3-button reddo-font">Shop D</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content r-font">
        <a href="d-clothing.php">Clothing</a>
        <a href="d-makeup.php">Makeup</a>
        <a href="d-skin+hair.php">Skin + Hair</a>
        <a href="d-accessories.php">Accessories</a>
        <a href="d-household.php">Homeware</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The thing is all of  these links work on my homepage, they just stop working when I use the same code for a navbar on the individual pages the links lead to. I wanted to add the bar to the other pages just so I can have the ability to jump around pages without going back to the homepage. Would it still make sense to move the files to where the index folder is?

Comment: Hi. Please make a back up if you feel unsure. The easiest solution in this case for you is to move all pages/**.php files to the main folder where index.php is. Then in your current code above, delete all prefix 'pages/' for all href. Then re-use the edited navbar code for all other pages.

Comment: Here I explain why your current way not working for 1 link. The same issue to all other links. Say we are in page pages/a-clothing.php, you click on link 'Home', by your code, the location is href="index.php", i.e. telling server find a file called index.php in the same folder where file pages/a-clothing.php locates. Clearly the same folder which is folder 'pages' does not contain file index.php.  Server hence returns 404 error for reason 'I can not find pages/index.php'.

Comment: Similarly. Say we are in page pages/a-clothing.php, you click on link Shop A 'Makeup'. By your code, the location is href="pages/a-makeup.php", i.e. telling server find a file called a-makeup.php in sub folder pages/pages/a-makeup.php relatively with pages/a-clothing.php locates. Server hence returns 404 error for reason 'I can not find pages/pages/a-makeup.php'.

Comment: After fixing done as listed, let me know the outcome. Enjoy :)

Comment: How's thing ...?

Comment: I just tried this and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great that you got it :). If my codes solves it well, please tick and upvote my code to mark it as the solution for this topic.